# ffmpeg - sweeping opacity

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I have two videos of 1 minute each one. I would like to start the second video at the 50 seconds of the first one.

Then I would like to decrease the opacity of the first video from 100% to 0 in the 50-60 seconds range, and to increase the opacity of the second video from 0 to 100% in the same range.

Is this possible with ffmpeg?

If yes, could you give me a code for that?

Thank you

Comment: This is a crossfade. Use the xfade filter - http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#xfade.

Comment: Thank you, it is solved